# Is there a way to create executable files in Python without os.chmod for *nix systems?

Tags: python, unix, umask

By default `open` writes files with 666 octal permission: -rw-rw-rw-. I wonder if there's a way to make `open` creates files with the execution bit set. For instance,  if presumably my system's umask value is 0000 then any file written with `open` will be written with the permission -rw-rw-rw-:

```
$ umask 
0000
```

`>>> open("aaa", "w")`

```
$ ls -l aaa
-rw-rw-rw- 1 Kuser Kuser 0 Jun 19 08:44 aaa
```

I'm looking for a way to set the default permission value of `open` to 777 octal so I can write executable files directly without `os.chmod`. Or generally is there a way to achieve this in Python? Probably using lower-level file processing tools from `os` module? `touch` and most editors use 666 octal permission mode by default.

I wasn't able to obtain files with the execution bit set for files created by `touch` command, `touch` uses 666 by default.

*Note: this just an artificial question.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) accepts an `opener` argument that returns a file descriptor; [`os.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) accepts a mode, which defaults to `0o777`.

```
import os

with open("aaa", "w", opener=os.open) as f:
    ⋮
```